# How to cater to 2 different audiences in1 page

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, design, page-layout

I'm working on 1 site page that is for both Enterprise customers and Communications Service Providers. We sell the same offers and solutions to both but we need to use a different language for each. For example Enterprise would use the solutions for themselves and CSP's would use it to sell it to enterprise customers.

We've already thought of using tabs to separate the content, and of making the user select who they are near the begining of the page... is there anything else we could do here?

Comment: Why does it have to be in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

What is the business goal of the website? If it is to convert visitors to prospects, it might be a good idea to have two domains for traffic channeling.

Suppose your primary customer segment is Enterprise clients. In that case, your main website should communicate that promptly by making it the only information to be displayed (you can have a link to the other site in the footer).